# How to prevent FlatList items from scrolling underneath sticky ListHeaderComponent

Tags: react-native

I have a `FlatList` with a `ListHeaderComponent` which is a number of buttons in a horizontal scroll. I have made these buttons sticky so that it stays at the top during scroll but is there a way to prevent the scrolled items from showing beneath the buttons as I scroll up? I have tried adding a `marginBottom` to `ListHeaderComponentStyle` but it does not work. I want the items to start disappearing just beneath the `ListHeaderComponent` how do I do this?

```js
<FlatList
        style={{marginTop: 50}}
        data={data}
        ListHeaderComponent={
          <FilterOptionButtons/>
        }
        ListHeaderComponentStyle={{ marginBottom: 50 }}  // does not add m
        stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={renderItems}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListContainer}
      />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `backgroundColor` style to the `ListHeaderComponent`. Currently it is transparent that's why the items are showing beneath it.

Also, I think it would be better if you just add style to the container of `<FilterOptionButtons />` instead of using `ListHeaderComponentStyle`.